# How to setup PDO Informix (php_pdo_informix) with PHP version 8 (8.0 and/or 8.1)?

Tags: laravel, informix, php-8.1

My project is running on PHP-laravel(PHP 8.0) + vuejs. I'm trying to set up pdo Informix with PHP. Firstly, I tried using docker setup (including PHP 8.0, Nginx, MSSQL, Debian) and then I tried with wamp setup. I have set up IBM client SDK for both setups and neither did work for me. Below given is the setup information.

IBM Informix Client-SDK version-for windows: 4.50.FC8
IBM Informix Client-SDK version-for Linux Debian: clientsdk.4.10.FC15.linux-x86_64
PDO Informix version: PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.6

Hello friends,
I'm using docker setup for the development, windows server 2019 hosting on IIS on the test and production.

1. When tried with docker setup, the installation gets completed but while running the connection test it skips all 33 tests. It shows the pdo_informix.so extension in the PHP's ext directory but cannot succeed with the Informix DB connection.
2. When I tried with wamp setup (which includes thread-safe dll) it worked for me but I couldn't apply it on test/production. Also, I tried installing PHP 8.1 on IIS which requires non-thread-safe dlls.
   I found this link [https://github.com/Aevis/php_pdo_informix] but was unable to find the non-thread-safe  php_pdo_infomix.dll for PHP 8.1. If anyone can help me with the solution either with docker or with windows (non-thread safe dll) setup it would be a great help. I have tried almost all available links on stack overflow and other sites.
   I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found the solution using **PHP-8.1.12 NTS (non-thread-safe) dll**. I have compiled it on my local machine and I'm sharing the references for easy availability.
I have to compile it using phpsdk-vs16-x64 compiler.
Please use the below video for step-by-step guidance or you can use the link below it, but I would strongly suggest going through the video once.

- Video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVnfw5exxGI
- Page link: https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2

If you are stuck anywhere while building an extension I strongly recommend visiting the below link. [image]
Check the image for reference for the part you have to refer to if you face an error.
[Cannot find php_pdo_informix.dll for PHP 8.1.9 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73447485/cannot-find-php-pdo-informix-dll-for-php-8-1-9-on-windows)
Also, I'm sharing the built extension below. https://github.com/Aevis/php_pdo_informix/files/10029625/php_pdo_informix-1.3.6-8.1.12-vs16-nts-x64.zip

At last, I'm thankful for the reference video, links which helped to build the required extension.
References:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCg7ccVTrH9g3pX_7d_Y2ZpQ
[Cannot find php_pdo_informix.dll for PHP 8.1.9 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73447485/cannot-find-php-pdo-informix-dll-for-php-8-1-9-on-windows)
https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2